# Infragistics WebDataGrid- How do I get the value typed into the filter box by the user?

Tags: filter, infragistics, webdatagrid

Using an Infragistics WebDataGrid v11.2 , how do I get the value typed into the filter box by the user, from the C# codebehind?

Say the column's Key="LastName" . After the webDataGrid performs the search on the value entered,  I would like to get the string that was entered in the filter box using C# on the next PostBack.

for example something like:

```
string ln = wdgNames.Columns.FindItemByKey("LastName").FilterValue ;
```

or

```
string ln = wdgNames.Rows[0]Items.FindItemByKey("LastName").FilterValue ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle grid `DataFiltering` or `DataFiltered` event, in there loop thru column filters (since you can have more than one) and get filter value according to column type.

For example the code snipped below gives access to string filters:

```
using Infragistics.Web.UI;

...

protected void grid_DataFiltering(object sender, GridControls.FilteringEventArgs e)
{
   for (int I = 0; I < e.ColumnFilters.Count; I++) {
      if (e.ColumnFilters[I].ColumnType == "string") {
         //((GridControls.RuleTextNode)e.ColumnFilters[I].Condition).Value will give you the filter value
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Got it to work.Curiously, 
Namespace GridControls is not recognized in visual studio :  GridControls.RuleTextNode  (cannot resolve ‘GridControls’) 
but  RuleTextNode is recognized using: 
Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls.RuleTextNode
or using
RuleTextNode

Comment: @LillLansey that's my bad, I assumed the `Infragistics.Web.UI` Namespace is imported via `using` - that's a good shortcut when working with long namespaces.

Comment: Also needed  o based indexing (int I = 0; I < e.ColumnFilters.Count-1; I++) {

Comment: There is a "using Infragistics.Web.UI.GridControls;" statement in the file. I guess that is why class RuleTextNode was found.  Anyway, thanks.

Comment: No problem and thanks for the correction. I will update the above code so that if anybody need it in the future it will be correct